# Basic JSON inserting nested entities into Spring boot (POST)

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-boot

So Im new at Spring boot and I ran into a small problem.I need to save 2 entities of Object, by POST call. The problem is saving a nested array of Objects inside of object.

JSON:

```
{ 
 "id": "100", 
 "department": "marand", 
 "patients": { 
 "patient": [ 
 { 
 "id": "1", 
 "first_name": "John", 
 "last_name": "Smith", 
 "diseases": { 
 "disease": [ 
 "nice_to_people", 
 "long_legs" 
 ] 
 } 
 }, 
 { 
 "id": "2", 
 "first_name": "Jenny", 
 "last_name": "Cox", 
 "diseases": { 
 "disease": [ 
 "used_to_have_dredds", 
 "nice_to_people" 
 ] 
 } 
 }, 
 { 
 "id": "3", 
 "first_name": "Martin", 
 "last_name": "Lewis", 
 "diseases": { 
 "disease": [ 
 "chocaholic", 
 "great_haircut" 
 ] 
 } 
 } 
 ] 
 } 
 }
```

I have 2 Entities Doctor and Patient with class constructors:

Doctor without getters and setters:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "doktors")
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@JsonIgnoreProperties({"hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler"})
public class Doktor implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialversionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;


    @Column(name = "department")
    private String department;

    @Autowired
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "doktor",cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<Patient> patients;
```

and Patient without getters and setter:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "patient")
@JsonIgnoreProperties({"hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler"})
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
public class Patient  implements Serializable {
        private static final long serialversionUID = 1L;

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        private Long id;

        @Column(name = "first_name")
        private String first_name;

        @Column(name = "last_name")
        private String last_name;



        @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
        @JoinColumn(name = "doktor_id",nullable = false)
        @JsonIgnore
        private Doktor doktor;

       @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
        @JoinTable(name = "patient_disease", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "patient_id",referencedColumnName = "id"),
               inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "disease_id",referencedColumnName = "id") )
        private List<disease> diseases;
```

so when I insert the JSON into POST call I get the following error: **{"timestamp":1613060297379,"status":400,"error":"Bad Request","message":"JSON parse error: Cannot deserialize instance of `java.util.ArrayList<com.jakob.demo.Pacient.Patient>` out of START_OBJECT token; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize instance of `java.util.ArrayList<com.jakob.demo.Pacient.Patient>` out of START_OBJECT token\n at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 4, column: 14] (through reference chain: com.jakob.demo.Doktor.Doktor["patients"])","path":"/api/doktors"}**

Answer (score 1):

Your classes does not accomodate the json. The "patient" field should be removed from "patients".
The "patients" field should look like this:

"patients": [
{
"id": "1",
"first_name": "John",
"last_name": "Smith",
"diseases": {
"disease": [
"nice_to_people",
"long_legs"
]
}
},
{
"id": "2",
"first_name": "Jenny",
"last_name": "Cox",
"diseases": {
"disease": [
"used_to_have_dredds",
"nice_to_people"
]
}
},
{
"id": "3",
"first_name": "Martin",
"last_name": "Lewis",
"diseases": {
"disease": [
"chocaholic",
"great_haircut"
]
}
}
]